# group list of dict by tuple value

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I tried to solve this with list comprehension, itemgetter and groupby but I don't seem close.  Given this type of list of dict:

```
test_list = [{'text': "Hi",'bbox': (0,0)},
          {'text': "There.",'bbox': (1,0)},
          {'text': "Im",'bbox': (0,1)},
          {'text': "John.",'bbox': (1,1)},
         ]
```

I am looking for this result:

```
[['Hi',"There."],['Im','John.']]
```

Where the 'text' values are grouped by the second tuple element in the 'bbox'.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `groupby` approach. One line but not particularly readable.

```
from itertools import groupby

test_list = [
    {'text': "Hi",'bbox': (0,0)},
    {'text': "There.",'bbox': (1,0)},
    {'text': "Im",'bbox': (0,1)},
    {'text': "John.",'bbox': (1,1)},
]

result = [[s['text'] for s in groups] for _, groups in groupby(test_list, key=lambda x: x['bbox'][1])]

print(result)
```

Note this happens to work because the input is sorted appropriately already, but if it wasn't, it would need to be sorted first before calling `groupby`.

Answer (score 3):

You can easly achieve this task using [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) from `collections` module:

```
from collections import defaultdict


test_list = [
    {'text': "Hi",'bbox': (0,0)},
    {'text': "There.",'bbox': (1,0)},
    {'text': "Im",'bbox': (0,1)},
    {'text': "John.",'bbox': (1,1)},
]

out = defaultdict(list)
for k in test_list: 
    out[k['bbox'][1]].append(k['text'])

# print(out.values())
print(list(out.values()))
# [['Hi', 'There.'], ['Im', 'John.']]
```

**Update:**

You can also use Python's default `dict` object like this example:

```
out = {}
for k in test_list:
    key, value = k['bbox'][1], k['text']
    if key in out:
        out[key].append(value)
    else:
        out[key] = [value]

print(list(out.values()))
# [['Hi', 'There.'], ['Im', 'John.']]
```

Comment: that def works - thanks.  I would be interested in seeing a native dict solution as well if someone has one.

Answer (score -2):

Sorry for double posting, I can not comment yet.
In cases, in which the elements are not sorted already, the library-free solution of @Chiheb Nexus will contain the correct groupings but not necessarily in the correct order. As the order criterion is discarded in the operation, this might be unfavourable but the question did not specify this. The same holds for the ordering of the elements within each grouping.
Ordering the `out` dictionary by key before converting to a list would order the groupings and keeping the first entry of the `bbox` attribute would enable sorting each grouping by that entry.